# How to add signalr to an angular project?

Tags: c#, angular, visual-studio-2017

I created an MVC/Angular project by using:

```
dotnet new angular
```

The project was created successfully and can be opened in Vs2017.

I've also added a `nuget.config` file with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="AspNetCore" value="https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-ci-dev/api/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="NuGet" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Examples on the net show how to add `SignalR` manually in the `project.json` file.

However, the created project doesn't have this file.

So I can I add `SignalR` to my project?

Comment: Have you tried installing SignalR Nuget package? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR

Comment: Also, there is a good example in https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/884647/Web-app-using-Web-API-SignalR-and-AngularJS